# Do Java's regular arrays have built in methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I know that a regular Java array `int[] arr = new int[5];` lives in the heap and therefore it is considered as an object. Although it is considered as an object it is different from other Java obects because it cannot do everything that other Java objects can.

One of the books I read about Java says, that

> "Even though an array is an object, it lives in its own special world
>   and you can't invoke any methods on it, although you can access its
>   one and only instance variable, length"

This book is based on java 5.0.

I am using netbeans as an IDE, and strangely enough I noticed that some methods can be invoked on the array object "arr".

```
arr.equals()
arr.clone()
arr.getClass() --> this gives class [I, and I don't know what it means
```

Was the book wrong, or were these methods introduced in recent versions? And what is `class [I`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array is a reference type, which means it's a sub-class of `Object`. Therefore all the methods of `Object` can be invoked on arrays. Perhaps the book meant that arrays don't introduce any array specific methods.

`[I` is the class name of an int array (`int[]`).

Comment: ...but no, they don't have any additional ones of their own, hence `java.util.Arrays` and such.

Comment: yeah that is why there is an Arrays class which offer static methods to provide different operations on arrays

Comment: does it mean somebody at sun wrote class [I extends Object

Comment: @DesirePRG No, since arrays are a special case. There's no Java source code of the array class (well, there is a java.lang.reflect.Array class, but it's only used for reflection).

Answer (score 1):

All methods above you referred is inherited from `Object`. `Object` in Java API is an object too. Every class you createed ended with `.java` is by default inherited from `Object`. Of course `even though an array is an object`, and `Every thing is an object`

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1

Each array has an associated object that you can access through the array identifier. That object has a class, and that class implements the interfaces `Serializable` and `Cloneable`.

So, you can call any of the methods inherited from Object, and `clone()` from `Cloneable`. `Serializable` has no methods.

Your book is wrong - although depending on the level of the book, it might be a forgivable white lie.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge,

getClass will invoke toString() method which in turn invokes getName() method.

So,
int[] arr = new int[5];

when you execute arr.getClass(), it will call toString method and internally getName() method is invoked.

so the result what you have obtained is [I.

The other array type are mentioned here,

```
byte[] me = new byte[1];
int[] me2 = new int[1];
double[] me3 = new double[1];
float[] me4 = new float[1];
String[] me5 = new String[1];
Integer[] me6 = new Integer[1];

System.out.println(me.getClass());                  
System.out.println(me2.getClass());                 
System.out.println(me3.getClass());                 
System.out.println(me4.getClass());                 
System.out.println(me5.getClass());
System.out.println(me6.getClass());

[B
[I
[D
[F
[Ljava.lang.String;
[Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

I think this will help you.

Thanks